# Problems verifying SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, fedora, signing

For school we are currently studying SSL certificates.

For this week's assignment we had to install Fedora Workstation on VirtualBox and do some SSL-stuff.

One of the assignments was the following:

> generate a public/private keypair and a CSR with the openssl command.

I generated a public/private keypair using the following command:

```
openssl genrsa -out Desktop/mykey.key 2048
```

After I generated the keypair I had to verify it. But how do you verify a key? What is really meant by that? Just get out the public key and check if it matches the private key? **This is the first question.**

I generated the CSR using the following command:

```
openssl req -new -key Desktop/mykey.key -out Desktop/myCSR.csr
```

This is the right way, right?

Checking/verifying the CSR file was done using this command:

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in Desktop/myCSR.csr
```

I think that's the right way too.

This was the "easy" part, now comes the harder part:

We had to use xca to create a database and a CA Root Certificate. Then we had to import the csr from above question and sign it. I signed it by right clicking on it and choosing **sign**. Then we had to export both the CA and the signed key and verify it. But what do they mean exactly? My guess is to verify that the certificate is signed by the CA, but I'm having problems with that.
We have to use openssl x509 for that, but it just isn't working.

When I right click the signed key and export it as a PEM file, in that file is the following:

```
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST -----
MIIC6......
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST -----
```

while the assigment says: export the signed certificate. But is this even a certificate?

And how do I verify it?

I used many commands, like

```
openssl x509 -in Desktop/exported.pem -text -noout
```

But the output I get is always something like this:

[image: screenshot]

I have tried all sorts of commands and read all google pages, but nothing helps.
**this is the second question**

Hope you all can help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you verify a certificate, you are checking whether it's CA is recognised, and it matches the CA's fingerprint. It doesn't look like you are providing the CA cert to the `openssl` command. Try specifying `-CA <your CA cert file`:

```
 $ openssl x509 --help
...
 -CA arg         - set the CA certificate, must be PEM format.
```

Comment: Well, thank you! As it seems, I didn't export the certificate, but the CSR I imported before. In xca: `Certificates tab > Expand CA > Export certificate` is the way to export it. Then I used `openssl verify -CAfile MyRootCA.crt MySignedCert.crt` which returns `OK`! So that works. Bit is this even possible with `openssl x509`? It doesn't have the `verify` command ...

Comment: sorry `x509` was typo :)

Comment: Okay :) So verifying using `x509` isn't even possible? The manual from school I follow is just wrong. Cited: "Export the CA and signed certificates and check it with the `openssl x509` command"

Comment: Yeah, I guess, I suppose we could blame it on falling academic standards, but I guess it's an easy mistake to make!

Comment: I tell a lie! You can use the `x509` command to verify a *csr*, not a certificate. Have a look half way down here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs there's nuance to this stuff.

Comment: I see, you're right. And what about the question `Generate and check a RSA public/private keypair and CSR using openssl`. For generating the keypair I used `openssl genrsa -out MyKey.key 2048` which outputs a file with a private key in it. For generating the CSR I used `openssl req -new -key MyKey.key -out MyCSR.csr` and `openssl req -text -noout -verify -in MyCSR.csr` for checking it. But how would you go about checking (I think they mean `verifying` a keypair? It's a difficult subject  ;)

Comment: Have a look at the second last command here :) https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064